# Shortest Ruby one-liner to execute a statement exactly once

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm looking for the shortest, most simple Ruby one-liner to execute a statement exactly once. Idea is to use this while debugging to quickly add a debug statement to a loop that gets executed exactly once.

Best I've come up with so far:

```
puts "do something interesting exactly once!" if (once ||= "0").next! == "1"
```

Can you come up with something even shorter?

*Added for clarification:*

The idea for the questions was to focus on the "do it once" part and not so much on the "do something interesting" part. It should be assumed that the code do be executed once could be anything, not just a puts statement.

The ideal solution would also work in different kinds of loop constructs. E.g. as was pointed out my initial solution only works if the `once` variable is already defined outside the loop context or if the loop context used doesn't create a new lexical scope.

The original use case that triggered this question was slightly different - it looked more like below. But I though the above, simpler example would more easily explain the kind of solution I was looking for.

```
def process
  do_some_preprocessing()

  raise SomeError if <once> # added temp. for debugging purposes - the <once> part is what this question is about!
  dangerous_operation() # this can raise SomeError under certain conditions

rescue SomeError
  attempt_to_rescue() and retry
end
```

Comment: BTW, your current code doesn't act like you say it does, does it?

Comment: Just one word comes to mind: **why?** Do you not want the code to be readable? Is this just a challenge? (If so, is off topic, there's a different SE for that)

Comment: I'll play along: `puts once = "do something interesting exactly once!" unless once`.

Comment: Patrice (and others who have pointed this out) - yes, it works but depends on the kind of looping construct in which it is used. For other kinds of context an instance variable can be used, e.g. `@once` instead of `once.

Comment: Arran - no, the goal is not the most readable code but code that requires the least amount of typing. As I stated (maybe not clearly enough) the idea is to just add this code temporarily for the purpose of debugging. Once done, I'll remove it from the code again. Just like you would add any other print statement to the code temporarily for debugging to find out the value of some variable - except I only want to print it once in this case.

Comment: Cary - I like it! Except that it mixes the "do something interesting" part with the "do it only once" part which can be a problem. E.g. in the specific use case that triggered my question the "do something interesting" part was to raise an exception. But I needed to raise it only the first time around to quickly test/debug an issue with recovery handling that's part of the looping construct. But in this question I wanted to focus on the "do it once" part so I choose a simpler puts statement.

Comment: @JanHecking Thanks for clarifying your question. Side note: when you're specifically addressing someone in comments, use the @ sign. The person will receive a notification (we do not keep track of all the discussions we're involved into). The owner of the post automatically receives notifications for all comments on his post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(answer edited to reflect the discussion in comments)*

Your code won't do what you want it to do, it will depend of the looping construct you use.

This will work:

```
puts "do something interesting exactly once!" if once = once.nil?
```

But with this one, you'll have to define `once` before: `once = nil` (same thing for your own code). This is because otherwise, the scope of the `once` variable will be restrained to the block within an `each` loop, causing it to fail. This would work just fine within a `for loop` (the way you must have tested it):

```
(1..3).each do    # 3.times would behave just the same
  puts "once has not been defined before! Won't work!" if once = once.nil?
end
# >once has not been defined before! Won't work!
# once has not been defined before! Won't work!
# once has not been defined before! Won't work!

for i in 1..3 do
  puts "Works because of the way for loops treat vars within loop" if once = once.nil?
end
# >Works because of the way for loops treat vars within loop
```

To avoid that problem without having to initialize the variable first, you can make `once` global:

```
(1..3).each do
  puts "$once's scope is not restrained to the 'each' loop! Works!" if $once = $once.nil?
end
# >$once's scope is not restrained to the 'each' loop! Works!
```

Comment: If you don't define `once` before, `once.nil?` will fail. I think. Can't test.

Comment: No it won't! it works as you expected printing once if `once =nil` was set before ..if you don't mind i could edit with some test code

Comment: If `once` is undefined, `once = once.nil? => true` (even though `once.nil? => undefined`); next, `true = once.nil => false` (no print). Thereafter `false = once.nil => false` (no print). Ha!

Comment: @Nimir Make yourself at home.

Comment: @Nimir, here's something interesting: change `3.times do` to `for i in (1..3)`. You'll see that causes `"do something..." to be printed just once.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That would work? This begins to be very interesting.

Comment: @Nirim, I lost my internet for awhile. `once = once.nil => true` but `once = twice.nil?` raises an "undefined local variable or method" exception, so I assume in the first case Ruby executes the right side after creating the variable `once`, which initially has the value `nil`.  Make sense? I don't understand why `each` and `for` behave differently, but it appears to be related to scope.  `for` mimics the execution of `"do something interesting exactly once!" if once = once.nil?` three times in a row, which is how I tested initially.

Comment: Sweat, short and simple! :-) I'll pick this as the best answer since it serves my purposes best (which I hope I've clarified in my last update).

Comment: @Nirim, I just read [this](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) article by Peter (the Great) Cooper. Near the end he confirms my guess about what's happening with `once = once.nil?`: an unassigned local variable is created before the right side is evaluated.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that's also why it seems impossible to fiddle with `defined?` to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could abuse lambdas and closures.

```
->{puts "do something interesting exactly once!";x=->{x}}[][]
#=> do something interesting exactly once!
#=> #<Proc:0x5465282c@(irb):10 (lambda)>
```

The original contents of the lambda are only run once; any subsequent invocations will simply return an empty proc.

You could alternately abuse globals for a more true "one-liner", but it's awful.

```
$x ||= puts("do something interesting exactly once!") || 1
```

Comment: +1 because I never thought about a self-modifying lambda, which could be useful. (You should show it prints once.)

Comment: Doesn't work. Try: `5.times do
  x = ->{puts "do something interesting exactly once!";x=->{}}
  x.call
end`  Your answer is similar to trying: `x=true; puts 'hello' if x; x=false;`

Comment: @7stud Yes but he would define the lambda outside of the loop. And then `call` it in the loop.

Comment: @Partice Gahide, Then why bother with the lambda?  You can just write `x=true; 5.times {puts "hi" if x; x = false}`
`

Comment: +1 x will do a samurai seppuku (killing it self) after printing once :)

Comment: @7stud Because then you'll have two statements separated by a semi-colon. This would not be practical from OP's point of view (of course, whether or not what he's trying to achieve is practical is questionable too ;)

Comment: I like this solution because it's clever. But I like Patrice's much simpler solution better since I'm more likely to actually remember/use it next time I need to add a quick debug statement somewhere that should be execute exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

```
debug = ["do something interesting exactly once!"]
puts debug.pop # "do something interesting exactly once!"
puts debug.pop # nil
```

Answer (score 0):

The original idea generates code-smell. It results in code that will leave someone else scratching their head, which isn't a good thing. Generating code that is obvious and easy to understand will make your, and other programmer's, job easier.

Writing code that takes a while to figure out will take you a while to figure out in the future if you're debugging so be kind to your future self.

I'd stick with the standard way, using a simple flag:

```
once = false
2.times do
  puts "do something interesting exactly once!" unless once
  once ||= true
end
```

Which results in this output:

```
# >> do something interesting exactly once!
```

Comment: Working better isn't the question. Shorter is.

Comment: the string will never print, `(once ||= true)` always returns true

Comment: What I mean is that those "solutions" don't do what he wants in the first place. I can't test it right now but I'm pretty sure...

Comment: @Ali Yes this one won't show anything and OP's one will show up everytime.

Comment: `(once ||= true) always returns true`. Yep. Oh well. It's a bad idea to do what the OP wants anyway.